# React-Native while pressing customButton nothing happens but when i press return it works

Tags: react-native

While pressing RoundButton component nothing happens, but when I press press return it works,

Here is my custom Button component

**Custom Button**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, } from 'react-native';

export const RoundedButton = ({
  style = {},
  textStyle = {},
  size = 125,
  ...props
}) => {
  return( <TouchableOpacity style={[styles(size).radius,style]}>
  <Text style={[styles(size).text,textStyle]}>{props.title} </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>);
};
```

**Calling from component**:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import {TextInput} from "react-native-paper";
import {RoundedButton} from '../../components/RoundedButton'

export const Focus = ({addSubject}) => {
  const [focusSubject, setFocusSubject] = useState(null);
  const [tempItem, setTempItem] = useState(null);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
    <Text>Want something?</Text>
    <View  styles={styles.inputContainer} >
    <TextInput onSubmitEditing={({ nativeEvent }) => {
      setTempItem(nativeEvent.text);
addSubject(nativeEvent.text)
    }} />
    <RoundedButton size={100} title="+" onPress={()=> {addSubject(tempItem)}} />
    </View>
    </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call onPress on TouchableOpacity

**Custom Button**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, } from 'react-native';

export const RoundedButton = ({
  style = {},
  textStyle = {},
  size = 125,
  ...props
}) => {
  return( 
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onButtonHandler} style={[styles(size).radius,style]}>
  <Text style={[styles(size).text,textStyle]}>{props.title} </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)};
```

In your component pass onButtonHandler

**Calling from component**:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet,TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import {TextInput} from "react-native-paper";
import {RoundedButton} from '../../components/RoundedButton'

export const Focus = ({addSubject}) => {
  const [focusSubject, setFocusSubject] = useState(null);
  const [tempItem, setTempItem] = useState(null);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
    <Text>Want something?</Text>
    <View  styles={styles.inputContainer} >
    <TextInput onSubmitEditing={({ nativeEvent }) => {
      setTempItem(nativeEvent.text);
addSubject(nativeEvent.text)
    }} />
    <RoundedButton size={100} title="+" onButtonHandler={()=> {addSubject(tempItem)}} />
    </View>
    </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: it is even better and recommended nowadays use the [Pressable](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable) component instead of the ```TouchableOpacity```.

Comment: Its depends on situation..If you don't want any touchable effect then its recommended to use Pressable if user needs some touchable effect then we can use TouchableOpacity etc..

Comment: It worked thanks a lot i was trying to fix this for quite a long